# How to share libraries between two webpack-built applications?

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

I have two JavaScript single-page applications in two separate GIT repositories. I want to keep them separated as much as possible (different teams working on them etc.), but they are still very closely related and even co-exist within the context of the same web page as part of one large SPA. Naturally, these two applications share large amounts of library code and it is very wasteful to bundle each with its own copy of libraries.

Is there any way I can reuse the library code? What would be a possible approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am describing *seems* to be achievable using the [DLL plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/). Basically, I create a `vendor.js` file, which requires all of the dependencies. Then, from that file generate a bundle of all the libraries and a `manifest.json` file. Then, using `DllReferencePlugin` it should be possible to tell webpack in each of my apps to take the dependency from the vendor bundle. Both apps can be built independently. As a last step, simply load of the three bundles on the page.